# ¿Como acceder a un valor de un campo en la base de datos sin usar los atributos del objeto en Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

¿Hay alguna manera de acceder a los valores de los campos en la base de datos, sin tener que usar los atributos del objeto?.
Me refiero a evitar tener que hacer esto:

```
>>> from biblioteca.models import Libro
>>> libros=Libro.objects.all()
>>> for libro in libros: print(libro.titulo) # ¿como evito tener que acceder de esta manera al valor?
"el gran libro de django"
```

Pretendo evitar acceder de esta manera a los campos de la base de datos, para crear una vista generica que reciba como parametro un modelo, y luego muestre en una tabla las columnas y filas asociadas a ese modelo. Cuya vista desconoce por completo los atributos del modelo.

Comment: Lleva el modelo a diccionario (model to dict)

Comment: Podrías utilizar el método [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values), que devuelve un QuerySet, que devuelve un diccionario, en lugar de instancias, o [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list),  que devuelve tuplas, en lugar de instancias.